# How to run a job only when merging into a specific branch

Tags: git, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm running into a rather strange issue with my gitlab build script. I want to set up rules such that the build job will run ONLY on a merge request targeted to a specific branch. I added the following section to my build script:

```
build-dev:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - development
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "develop"
      when: always
    - when: never
#  extends: .build-base
  script:
    - echo $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE detected. Running the build script for $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME
  allow_failure: false
```

When I do a check in to a local branch, I would expect the job not to run. Instead it runs and I get the output

> merge_request_event detected. Running the build script for develop

So even though I did not create a merge request and the check in is on my local branch, gitlab still thinks I am making a merge request to 'develop'. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs across this, I found the answer. I forgot that I had an open merge request for the development branch. So even though I was doing a 'push' it was being appended to the open merge request.